# Is there a way to update and delete gridview fields in ASP.NET connected by MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, gridview

I cannot find a descend code for my gridview update and delete.
And also my Web form is connected with Mysql

I have tried some youtube tutorials but nothing helps. Or Am I just not getting the procedure

I expect 2 buttons "Update"&"Delete" respectively for a gridview which gets values from Mysql Database

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="test1.aspx.cs" Inherits="test1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" CellSpacing="2" >
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="br_id" HeaderText="Brand ID" SortExpression="br_id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="br_name" HeaderText="Brand Name" SortExpression="br_name" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />

        </asp:GridView>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Source Code**

```
 public partial class test1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        String mycon = "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=ecommerce; User Id=root;password='' ";
        String myquery = "Select * from brand";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(mycon);
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = myquery;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();

}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see the [ask] help page and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) blog post by Jon Skeet.

Comment: I am new to ASP.net please help me

Comment: try to follow below link for CRUD operation with My SQL https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-MySQL-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-and-Delete-in-GridView-using-MySQL-database-in-ASPNet.aspx

Comment: Please dont downvote this question. Atleast clear me the problem.

Comment: one more thing please put some effort and show us some code we are here to correct your error code but not to guide you from the scratch for how to do coding :)

Comment: @KevinShah I read that article. Still concept not cleared

Comment: firstly just try step by step. write code to bind grid on page load and then go for Edit and rebind the grid then go ahead. understand the code step by step with implementation

Comment: check out the edit. @KevinShah

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/editing-data-using-asp-net-gridview-control). It covers all the basics of GridView editing and updating. It does not matter if it is MS SQL or MySQL

Comment: And wrap all the code in your `Page_Load` inside an `IsPostBack` check.

Comment: @VDWWD I have this was just the portion of the file